# Регулярка: как выбрать email, но не в кавычках

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, email

На входе строка: 
"email.email.com" email.email.com, "other@email.com" other@email.com

нужно регуляркой выбрать емайлы, но только те, которые не в кавычках

Comment: а как email разделяются между собой? а то иначе возникает пачка неоднозначностей.

Comment: могут быть пробелы или запятые, но обычно идет парами - емайл в кавычках, емайл без кавычек, запятая, и опять так-же несколько раз... в кавычках может быть имя человека вместо email или вообще ничего, но факт, что выбрать нужно только "вторые" емайлы, которые в паре идут без кавычек...

Comment: тогда может так и парсить, парами? Где то такой регуляркой `"[^"]+"\s+([^"@]+@[^@]+)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно отталкиваться от следующего регулярного выражения

```
<?php
  $string = '"email.email.com" email.email.com, "other@email.com1" other@email.com';
  preg_match_all(
    '/\b(?<!")([-0-9a-z_\.]+@[-0-9a-z^\.]+\.[a-z]{2,})(?!")\b/',
    $string,
    $out);
  echo "<pre>";
  print_r($out);
  echo "<pre>";
```

Comment: спасибо, рабочий вариант

Comment: @norgen Вы сказали, что в кавычках может быть произвольный текст. Имейте в виду, данный вариант выделит оба email из строки: `" abc@abc.com " xyz@abc.com` т.е. если внутри кавычек будут пробелы, то содержимое этих кавчек запросто может быть воспринято как email

Comment: @Mike благодарю за уточнение, это предусмотрено. По логике между кавычками и текстом внутри самих кавычек пробелов не должно быть.